# Use a variable while traversing data given by subscribe in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-observable

```
getspacecol(){
this.gets=true;
this.selectedfeatures=[];
this.variantService.getData().subscribe((dat) => {
  this.dataa = dat;

   for(let i=0;i<this.selectedItems.length;i++)
   {
    this.tool=this.selectedItems[i].itemName;
    }
  console.log(this.tool);
  for(let i=0 ; i<this.dataa.length;i++){

    if(this.dataa[i].this.tool===this.searchResult.value)//error in this.tool
     {
      this.selectedfeatures.push(this.dataa[i]);               
     }      
  }
  this.data=[...this.selectedfeatures];
});
}
```

Hi guys, there are 200 columns in my table and there is angular2 multiselect dropdown containg 200 columns as dropdown values. I get the dropdown selected value in variable selectedItems
In the if condition if i give this.dataa[i].stackover there is no error as stackover is one of the column. Same stackover is present in dropdown and is printed in console.log when selected.

Now i need to use this variable in if condition in **this.dataa[i].this.tool** or else i will have to write if conditions for 200 columns
Can you guys please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

In if loop `this.dataa[i].this.tool`, this.tool is considered as the key name and its trying to find the "this.tool" key in your object which is not correct so, you should be using a following syntax to achieve the same.

Example:

```
var keyName = this.tool
this.dataa[i][keyName]
```